# Q: How would you make a html drop down list with countries that opens up content on webpage depending on what country you choose?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm trying to create a drop down list in html for countries that would open different content on the website depending on which country one would choose. Would this be possible to do just purely on html? Thanks in advance.

[Demonstration of a drop down list that opens content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tATIh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that would work for you. Unfortunately you need to use a little bit JS if you want to manipulate the DOM.

```js
function changeContent() {
  let contents = [
    {country: "aus", content: "Australia!!!"},
    {country: "bel", content: "Belgia!!!"},
    {country: "geo", content: "Georgia!!!"},
  ]
  
  let selectedCountry = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  contents.forEach(location => {
    if(location.country == selectedCountry) {
      document.getElementById("selCountry").innerText = location.content;
    }
  })
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown" onchange="changeContent()">
  <option disabled selected value> -- countries -- </option>
  <option value="aus">Australia</option>
  <option value="bel">Belgia</option>
  <option value="geo">Georgia</option>
</select>

<div>Selected country: <span id="selCountry"><span/>
```